# Como puedo guardar información de una lista a un diccionario y hacer una suma con la información?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, math, spyder

Estoy haciendo el conteo de unos partidos, en el cual la informacion esta acomodada de la siguiente manera: "Primer equipo";"Segundo equipo";"Resultado para el primer equipo"
Tengo mi archivo csv sin títulos, con esta información:

America;Cruz Azul;Win

Cruz Azul;Chivas;Win

America;Chivas;Win

America;Cruz Azul;Draw

Eh logrado separarla y quitar los caracteres especiales:

```
w_d = 'C:/Users/c/OneDrive/Desktop/DM/DATA/'
f_i = w_d + 'data.csv'

text = []
with open (f_i, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_r:
    for line in f_r:
        text.append(line.strip())  

g1 = ''.join(text[0]).split(';')
g2 = ''.join(text[1]).split(';')
g3 = ''.join(text[2]).split(';')
g4 = ''.join(text[3]).split(';')
```

y ahora se que tengo que usar diccionarios para poder almacenar la información, pense en esta manera:

```
p1 = {"Position":"1", "Team":"America", "MP":[], "W":[],"D":[],"L":[], "Points":[]}
```

Aclarando que MP = numero de partidos jugados, W = victorias, D = Empates, L = Derrotas, y al final el numero de puntos obtenidos, y también por victoria obtenida se ganan 3 puntos y  por empate 1 punto, siguiendo con el diccionario que plantee arriba, me comentan que no es la mejor manera, y aquí es donde entra mi duda, cual seria la mejor manera en usar los diccionarios?